# Are there any double, triple star systems in No Man's Sky?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I've only come across single star systems. I'm curious to know if anyone has come across a double star system?

I've seen planets with two moons (albeit quite rare). Any double stars that I can look forward to?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

There are no multi-star systems in No Man's Sky.

In fact, not only can you only find single star systems, but the "star" of the system is not actually physically present. It's part of the [skybox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skybox_%28video_games%29) for that system.

Answer (score 11):

With the release of [No Man's Sky: Origins](https://www.nomanssky.com/origins-update), the most recent major update, systems with multiple stars now exist within the universe!

> Some rare systems are now home to multiple stars, creating stunning new patterns in the sky.
>
> [image: Binary star system]
>
> [....]
>
> **Star System Visuals**
>
> - Additional stars have been added to the universe.
> - Some systems now have binary stars.
> - There is a rare chance for a system to have ternary stars.

Answer (score 4):

I found a 3 star system and the stars are red green and blue. With a safe tropical planet. [image]