# Can we visit any star in No Man's Sky?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I was just wondering, What if I visit a **star**. I mean landing on a star (Sounds foolish and impossible), but I am curious. According to their statement : [every star in the sky is a sun that you can visit](http://www.no-mans-sky.com/about/), I wonder if they actually meant 'every star (star-system) in the sky is a sun that you can visit'; or it's a hint that we can actually visit/land on a star.

While jumping one planet to another within a system, we can see a star. What if we fly there? Did anyone try? I couldn't find any screenshots or videos of it. I could try. But I'm afraid of dying in space and losing all my collections and starships.

*P.S.: I can get a hint from question : [Are there any double, triple star systems in No Man's Sky?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/282370/are-there-any-double-triple-star-systems-in-no-mans-sky) 
But, I am pretty sure that is another question than mine. 
My question is Can we visit and if yes, can we land on a star? No matter how many number of stars available in a sytem.*

Question remains : Can we visit star? Any Idea?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, you can not reach a star. Stars are not actual objects, they are part of the background graphics of the star system. Only planets and moons can be landed on.

I thought I read this myself on another question/answer here but I can't find it.

Comment: You probably read in on [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/282372/80141) answer

Comment: That means, even if I try to visit star, I'll never be there. Ughh, just graphics. Thanks @udondan